# PHP Space in file name while building the img src

Tags: php

I am trying to display an image in a table from a query like this:

`echo ("<td> <img src=" . $row['img1'] . "></td>");`

This works until there is a space in the saved data. I am having the problem with the data entry    refimg\AMYLO A-1.jpg

It works with data that looks like this: refimg\BCL-2-1.jpg

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Is the problem php side or html side? As in: is the html printed correctly and the image requested?

Comment: Firstly, what URL has the image, and what URL are you viewing this page from?

Answer (score 1):

use `urlencode` to encode special character:

```
echo ("<td> <img src=" . urlencode($row['img1']) . "></td>");
```

Comment: Would quoting the content of the src attribute be enough?

Comment: urlencode seems to be the right track but we can't encode the entire URL but rather just the file name https://3v4l.org/MJmkE

Comment: @mickmackusa it sounds like `refimg\AMYLO A-1.jpg` was their input data here, and in that case vivek would be correct, that the whole path should probably not be URL-encoded as one single thing.

Comment: Ah, yes, the slash. @04FS I added another dupe to the list. (Probably more robust as a DIRECTORY SEPERATOR)

Comment: If I use the urlencode all my images wont be displayed instead of just the ones with a space in it.

Comment: @Remco yes, you will have to split your path first, so that the \ does _not_ get encoded as well. (Btw., rather bad to have a \ in your paths to begin with, URLs should always use /.)

Comment: the source is on a local server folder named refimg

Comment: Thanx ill try some of the options mentioned! The original code is not mine so I hope I don't have to change everything.